# Creating a child Pod with empty environment variable using operator results in an infinite loop

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-operator

I have a metacontroller (operator). It uses a custom CRD. When it gets a `sync` call, it creates a couple of child resources:

- Pod
- ServiceAccount
- Role
- RoleBinding

The pod is created with a valid image. In it's environment variables, there is one that is set with an empty string.

`{ "name": "PARTITIONS", "value": "" }`

This is returned to metacontroller. And the metacontroller starts creating the child objects.

Then it notices that there is a diff between the observed and actual state due to the `PARTITIONS` variable.

```
I0611 00:45:24.908380       1 manage_children.go:210] reflect diff: a=observed, b=desired:
object[spec][containers][0][env][11][value]:
  a: <nil>
  b: ""
```

And due to this it kills the started pod, and sends a sync request to my endpoint again.

This results in an infinite loop, because my endpoint looks at the request.children, notices pod missing, adds a new pod and returns. Which then again gets deleted after a while, ad infinitum.

Is this a bug in Metacontroller ?

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed on `metacontroller` project that this is a bug in how it serializes empty strings for comparing diffs.

Comment: Is there a ticket fir this? Was this fixes?

Comment: No, they said that it is by design.